# How to print first page only of a message?

Tags: vba, printing, outlook

Everything I found didn't work in version 2016 which I'm using.

I'm looking to print only the first page of the selected message.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Object Model does not give you much control over printing - `MailItem.PrintOut` is all you get. You'd be better off saving the message in the HTML or MHTML format, opening it in Word programmatically and printing it using [Application.PrintOut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.printout) (where `Application` is `Word.Application`).